# Elastic: I want to Write a Query (Peak volume per hour experienced at any time in the specific month)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I got total data for a month.
Now, I want to get peak volume per hour in that specific month with the help of query?

I am working with Kibana-Elastic.

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter query to filter the result, then use a aggregation on the result to achieve the peak. For the aggregation part u will need to use a [date histogram](http:////www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) combined with a [Max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) aggregation.

The Date Histogram splits the result into seperate buckets on which u can then use the max metric aggregation.

If u want futher help u will need to provide ur data structure as its rly complicated to help without knowing the data u wanna query.